# Finding the order of zero at 0 of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the order of zero at $z_0 = 0$ of $f(z) = \frac{sin^7 (z)}{z^4}.$

I am having difficulty answering this as $z_0 = 0$ is both a zero and a singularity.

Comment: Are you asking for $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)$? Is $z$ in $\Bbb R$ or in $\Bbb C$?

Answer (score 1):

$f(z) = \frac{\sin^7 (z)}{z^4}=f(z) = \frac{\sin^4 (z)}{z^4}*\sin^3z$

Since $\frac{\sin^4 (z)}{z^4} \to 1$ for $z \to 0$, $f $ has a removable singularity at $0$ and a zero of order $3$